# Downloading and Appending PDFs

Tags: python, url, pdf

I'm trying to download all the pdf urls from a website and append all the pdfs into a single file.  At the moment, I have a list of all the urls containing pdfs.  How can I download all the pdfs and append them together?  I've attached my code below.  I'm using Python 2.7.8.

```
# Download and merge pdfs
url_list = listofurl
for url in listofurl:
    outfile = os.path.basename(url)
    with open(outfile, 'w') as out:
        out.write(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
```

Comment: Can you put a comment in the sample code showing where the error occurs?

Comment: Can you show us trace info?

Answer (score 0):

For me the download works but it throws an exception at one point where a file is not found

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

I am not sure if python itself is able to merge the files. I would recommend using "pdftk" and call it via the 'subprocess' module once your files are on your harddisk.

On a linux system it works like this once 'pdftk' (an external and very practical pdf merger for the command line) is installed:

```
from subprocess import call

call(['pdftk', '*.pdf', 'cat', 'output', 'combined.pdf'])
```

It is not quite the most pythonic way but the easiest I can think of at the moment. Hope it helps.